# What is the $2$-adic order of the number $(2k+1)^n-1?$

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

If is possible to calculate   ${\rm ord}_2((2k+1)^n-1)$ where ${\rm ord}_2(N)$ means  the greatest non-negative integer $\nu$ such that $2^\nu$ divides $N$ and $n$ is odd?

After simplification I have 
$$
(1+2k)^n-1=1+\binom{n}{1} 2k+\binom{n}{2} (2k)^2+(2k)^n-1=2k\left(n+\binom{n}{2} (2k)+\cdots+(2k)^{n-1}\right).
$$
Thus 
$$
{\rm ord}_2((2k+1)^n-1)=1+{\rm ord}_2(k)+{\rm ord}_2(\underbrace{n+\binom{n}{2} (2k)+\cdots+(2k)^{n-1}}_{\text{odd number }})=1+{\rm ord}_2(k)+0.
$$
Am I right?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: You might want to look op [Lifting The Exponent Lemma](https://www.google.com/search?q=lifting+the+exponent)